# Writing leading zeros to an Access database

Tags: c#, sql

Using C# and SQL I need to write a telephone number to an Access database. The value gets written to the database but the leading zero is lost in the database itself. How can I keep the leading zero?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Text` field instead of a numeric one. Numeric fields do not retain formatting information (such as leading zeroes).

Comment: Isn't that bad practice?

Comment: Alright I changed the data type to text and just added an input mask in Access. The leading zero is still not being written to the database.

Comment: @BabyDoll It's bad practice to store numbers as text, but if formatting is important, then you're storing more than just the number, and in that case, text makes more sense.

Comment: @BabyDoll You may need to ensure that your C# application treats it as a text column, too.

Comment: Thanks hvd, I passed the parameters as the wrong data type to the SQL statement. It works fine now.

Comment: A telephone number should never be thought of as numeric due to the fact that you would more than likely never do any kind of numeric operation on it. Storing it as a text field is the best way to go.